# Canvas putImageData rendering inconsistent

Tags: javascript, canvas, safari

I'm looking into a very weird bug working with canvas putImageData. Here is the code snippet:

```
// Results contains an indexMap of size 90000 and rgbdata of size 360000, data from a 300*300px source canvas
var results = state.results;

// output_canvas is the target canvas element of 300*300px
var output_canvas = document.getElementById('output_canvas');
var context = output_canvas.getContext('2d');
var imageData = context.createImageData(300, 300);
var data = imageData.data;
for (var i = 0; i < results.indexMap.length; ++i) {
    if (results.segments[results.indexMap[i]].foreground) {
        data[4 * i + 0] = results.rgbData[4 * i + 0];
        data[4 * i + 1] = results.rgbData[4 * i + 1];
        data[4 * i + 2] = results.rgbData[4 * i + 2];
        data[4 * i + 3] = 255;
    } else {
        data[4 * i + 3] = 0;
    }
}
context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

I can get the correct image rendered on "output_canvas" on Mac chrome. But it failed to render on Safari and Firefox. The final image is cut off and looks twice as big in both dimensions. I suspect this being a browser issue for putImageData implementation but I couldn't find a confirmation from any official source. Does anyone has similar problem? Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE 11/16/17: https://jsfiddle.net/9r4cbfpk/5/. Here's a working proof of concept fiddle. It gives me different results on Safari and on Chrome.

UPDATE 11/17/17: Fixed fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9r4cbfpk/7/. The key takeaway is fixing window.devicePixelRatio. Fabric upscales the canvas behind the scene so the real image is twice bigger in both dimension. I ended up upscaling the dest canvas to match the result data.

Comment: Could you share a live example?

Comment: @Kaiido Please see my fiddle in the update.

Comment: You always get this imageData from a Fabric.js canvas? You are on a retina display? (I'm not so can't repro, on my machine all works the same between chrome FF and Safari). If so, disable [enableRetinaScaling](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#enableRetinaScaling) option, or take into account that your `<canvas>` element's size as been doubled and reshrinked by CSS, so that you can do the same on your `destCanvas`.

Comment: @Kaiido That is the exact issue. Thank you good sir.